# How do you delete a readonly entity in MS CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a quote entity that I want to delete, how do I do so after its state is set to closed?

Comment: You can try running a workflow which sets the state back to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I covered how to do this in a blog article a couple years ago. There are some entities that you can't put back into a deletable state using web services, like contracts.

http://crmscape.blogspot.com/2008/10/ms-crm-data-import-cleaning-up-mess.html

Answer (score 0):

You must re-open the quote to delete it... if I remember well the Close and Cancelled states are read only states.